Community episode where Starburns complains about his nickname?
I seem to remember an episode in which Starburns returned to Community (after allegedly being killed in Season 3).  After returning, Starburns complains  about how he doesn't like being called Starburns. Someone retorts his complaining, stating  something along the lines of "If you didn't want to be called Starburns, maybe you shouldn't have shaved your side burns in the shape of stars."
Which episode of the series contains this sentence?

You sure it wasn't "Advanced Criminal Law", episode 1.5? [Chang] -Silencio, por favor. Star-Burns, that means you. [Star-Burns] - My name's Alex, dude. [Chang] - Well, maybe you should spend five hours sculpting that in your face.

That really might be it. I do remember Chang saying it. I'll check it out, thanks!
